# Intellij: Is there a Global Directory Exclude by Pattern option?

Tags: intellij-idea

I have the same directory structure in all my projects.

I would just like to exclude the same directories every time, instead of choosing each directory for every project and having to select `Mark Directory as -> Excluded`

For Example:
`bower-components/`, `node-modules`, etc...

Is that possible? I couldn't find that option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Settings | Editor | File Types | Files and folders to ignore

(Note that applying it to `node-modules` might not be the best idea because if you do this, the JS support in IntelliJ IDEA will not see any declarations in any of the node modules that you use, so you'll lose on code completion and navigation support.)

Comment: This unfortunately removes `node_modules` from the Project view. Any other way just to exclude it?

Comment: What do you mean by "just exclude"?

Comment: When you use `Mark Directory As` -> `Excluded` - it's still visible in the Project view. Using your solution the directory is ignored and thus hidden in the Project view.