# Put tmp files in an external dir with Ember?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In Ember.js projects I always find it so disruptive that `ember server` creates such a massive dump of rapidly changing files to the tmp folder in my project directory.

I often create projects in a cloud-synced folder, so these files tend to hit my daemon over the head with a mallet.

Also, it messes up my IDE's indexing and I have to manually exclude it every time.

Is there a way to configure to run `ember s` to put tmp outside of my project directory? Putting it into /tmp or ~/.tmp would be great.

Comment: well, for almost every IDE you can globally configure to exclude the `tmp` folder from all projects. Also it's never a good idea to put source code on cloud-sync folders like dropbox. Use source control like `git` instead, and git doesn't play very well in cloud synced folders as well.

Comment: Do you know how to do this in JetBrains IDEs? I posted to their forums and haven't gotten a response yet.

I do use source control, but putting everything under cloudsync is great for 1. Syncing personal notes, files, non-VC'd assets across machines and 2. Making sure that my working directory is available as-is across my machines even if I'm between commits or haven't pushed in a while.

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35679636/intellij-is-there-a-global-directory-exclude-by-pattern-option). And cloudsync does not work well with `git` and other version control tools, or build tools like ember in general. If you use git I recommend a working branch to sync between machines, commit often (~every 20 minutes), and later squash before pushing to master.

Comment: Thanks! I came across this solution earlier, mention it in my Jetbrains post. Unfortunately, this doesn't affect IDE indexing and has other externalities (such as hiding the folder in the project viewer). For anyone arriving to this thread, there's a Jetbrains support thread here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-150784  which still hasn't seen implementation.

Comment: If you use https://github.com/Turbo87/intellij-emberjs it will automatically exclude `dist` and `tmp` from indexing, and as you can see from the README it has a few other nice features :)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to configure to run ember s to put tmp outside of my
>   project directory? Putting it into /tmp or ~/.tmp would be great.

short answer: no

long answer: the Ember CLI team has been working in this direction, but the work is not completed yet